# How to draw line connector using p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am having difficulty to create a straight line (green) connecting node A and node B as shown below, using p5.js.
Node A and Node B, users can drag to move. When moving the connector can still keep the connection state.
Is there any solution to this problem?

Example:
[image: data flow connector]

When user move
[image]

Comment: You need to give it your best attempt and explain specifically where you are struggling. 
 Please copy and paste your code and/or include a link to editor.p5js.org.  Like I can figure this out but I don't want to have to write the code to draw boxes A and B.

Comment: The general idea: the positions of A and B should be variables which you update with a mousemove handler.  Then you'll do some computations to figure out where the line should go based on comparing the positions of A and B.  If one is completely on top of the other then it would go between them.  If they overlay in the Y direction then the line goes underneath both.